# Update a nested array in document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have document named Patient, and each patient has an array of objects called consultation which has a bunch of attribute here is my Patient Model

```
const Patient = new Schema(
  {
    firstname: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    father: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      default: "/",
    },
    birthdate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    blood: {
      groupe: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
        trim: true,
      },
      rhesus: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
        trim: true,
      },
    },
    ......
    consultation: [
      {
        medecin: String,
        technicien: {
          type: String,
          default: "/",
        },
        date: Date,
        time: String,
        acte: String,
        poids: {
          type: Number,
        },
        taille: {
          type: Number,
        },
        saturation: {
          type: String,
        },
        ta: {
          type: String,
        },

        comment: {
          type: String,
          trim: true,
          default: "Pas de commentaire",
        },
        compterendu: {...},
         .....
}
```

when i try to update a patient consultation with express js here is my code

```
module.exports.updatePatientActe = async (req, res) => {
  const { id, idacte } = req.params;

  const {
    dateacte,
    time,
    acte,
    medecin,
    technicien,
    poids,
    taille,
    saturation,
    ta,
    comment,
    status,
  } = req.body.consultation;
  const state = status;
  let patient;
  const query = { id, "consultation._id": idacte };
  const updateDocument = {
    $set: {
      "consultation.$.medecin": medecin,
      "consultation.$.technicien": technicien,
      "consultation.$.date": dateacte,
      "consultation.$.time": time,
      "consultation.$.acte": acte,
      "consultation.$.poids": poids,
      "consultation.$.taille": taille,
      "consultation.$.saturation": saturation,
      "consultation.$.ta": ta,
      "consultation.$.comment": comment,
      "consultation.$.status": state === "oui" ? state : "non",
    },
  };
  patient = await Patient.findOneAndUpdate({
    query,
    updateDocument,
  });
  req.flash("success", "Acte à été modifé avec succès");
  res.redirect(`/patient/${id}`);
};
```

the code run without any error but i the update doesn't work
Whould you please help me

Comment: Try adding the `rawResult` option to findOneAndUpdate and inspect the return value. You will see how many documents your query is matching and if any were updated or not. You can do this with `await Patient.findOneAndUpdate(query, updateDocument, { rawResult: true })`. I think the way you are passing the arguments to findOneAndUpdate is also wrong, it should be `Patient.findOneAndUpdate(query, updateDocument)`

Comment: Thank you for the note Patient.findOneAndUpdate(query, updateDocument) but it still not working

Comment: Please add the `rawResult: true` option as I suggested and log the return value and post the result. E.g. `const result = await Patient.findOneAndUpdate(query, updateDocument, { rawResult: true }); console.log(result);`

Comment: I found the issue it was in the id i had to put _id instead of id in the query option const query = { _id:id, "consultation._id": idacte };